# How to avoid a cyclic dependency (circular reference) between 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design, design-pattern

I have 3 tables:

- People
- Post
- Likes

When I design the ER model it has a cyclic dependency:

```
         1:N
People --------< Post

         1:N
Post ----------< Likes

         1:N
People --------< Likes
```

The logic is:

- 1 people can have many posts.
- 1 post has many likes.
- 1 people can like many posts (created person cannot like his own post).

How can I remove this kind of cyclic design? Or is my db design wrong?

Answer (score 11):

## Business rules

Let us make some rewordings to the business rules you have presented:

- A `Person` creates **zero-one-or-many** `Posts`.
- A `Post` receives **zero-one-or-many** `Likes`.
- A `Person` manifests **zero-one-or-many** `Likes`, **each of wich** pertains to **one specific** `Post`.

## Logical models

Then, from such set of assertions, I have derived the two logical level **IDEF1X<sup>[1]</sup>** data models that are shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI4gK.jpg).

[image: Figure 1 - People and Posts Data Models]

### Option A

As you can see in the Option A model, `PersonId` **migrates<sup>[2]</sup>** from `Person` to `Post` as a FOREIGN KEY (FK), but it receives the **role name<sup>[3]</sup>** of `AuthorId`, and this attribute makes up, together with `PostNumber`, the PRIMARY KEY (PK) of the the `Post` entity type.

I assume that a `Like` can only exist in connection with a particular `Post`, so I have set up a `Like` PK that comprises of three different attributes: `PostAuthorId`, `PostNumber` and `LikerId`. The combination of `PostAuthorId` and `PostNumber` is a FK that makes the proper reference to the `Post` PK. `LikerId` is, in turn, a FK that establishes the suitable association with `Person.PersonId`.

With the aid of this structure, you ensure that a determined person can only manifest a single `Like` occurrence to the same `Post` instance.

#### Methods to prevent a Post Author from liking his own Post

Since you **do not** want to allow the possibility that a person can like his/her authored posts, once in the implementation phase, you should establish a method that compares the value of `Like.PostAuthorId` with the value of `Like.LikerId` in every INSERT attempt. If said values match, **(a)** you reject the insertion, if they do not match **(b)** you let the process continue.

In order to accomplish this task in your database, you can make use of:

1. A **CHECK CONSTRAINT** but, of course, this method excludes MySQL, since it has not been implemented in this platform so far, as you can see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) and [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464).
2. **Code lines** inside an [ACID Transaction](http://amturing.acm.org/info/gray_3649936.cfm#add_1).
3. **Code lines** within a **TRIGGER**, which could return a custom message indicating the rule violation attempt.

### Option B

If the author is not an attribute that identifies in a primary way a post in your business domain, you could go with a structure similar to the one depicted in Option B.

This approach also makes sure that a post can only be liked by the same person one single time.

---

## Notes

<sub>1. Integration Definition for Information Modeling (**[IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x.htm)**) is a **highly recommendable data modeling technique** that was defined as a **standard** in december 1993 by the United States National Institute of Standards and Technology (**NIST**).</sub>

<sub>2. IDEF1X defines **key migration** as “The modeling process of placing the primary key of a parent or generic entity in its child or category entity as a foreign key”.</sub>

<sub>3. A **role name** is a denotation assigned to a foreign key attribute in order to express the meaning of such attribute in the context of its corresponding entity type. Role naming is recommended since 1970 by [**Dr. E. F. Codd**](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm) in his seminal paper entitled **[“A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Data Banks”](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685)**. For its part, IDEF1X —keeping fidelity regards **relational** practices— also advocates this procedure.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

I don't see anything cyclic here. There are *people* and *posts* and two independent relationships between these entities. I would see *likes* as the implementation of one of these relationships.

- A person can write many posts, a post is written by one person: `1:n`
- A person can like many posts,  a post can be liked by many people: `n:m`
  The n:m relationship can be implemented with another relation: `likes`.

#### Basic implementation

The basic implementation could look like this in **PostgreSQL**:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  person_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, person    text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE post (
  post_id   serial PRIMARY KEY
, author_id int NOT NULL  -- cannot be anonymous
     REFERENCES person ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE  -- 1:n relationship
, post      text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE likes (  -- n:m relationship
  person_id int REFERENCES person ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
, post_id   int REFERENCES post ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
, PRIMARY KEY (post_id, person_id)
);
```

A post *must* have an author (`NOT NULL`), while the existence of any likes is optional. For existing likes, however, `post` and `person` *must* both be referenced - enforced by the `PRIMARY KEY` that makes both columns `NOT NULL` implicitly. So anonymous likes are impossible.

About the n:m implementation:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)

### Prevent self-like

You wrote:

> (created person cannot like his own post).

That's not enforced in the above implementation, yet. You could use a [***trigger***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).
Or one of these faster / more reliable solutions:

#### Rock-solid for a cost

If it needs to be **rock-solid**, extend the FK from `likes` to `post` to include `author_id` redundantly. Then you can rule out incest with a simple `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE likes (
  person_id int REFERENCES person ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
, post_id   int 
, author_id int NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT likes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (post_id, person_id)
, CONSTRAINT likes_post_fkey FOREIGN KEY (author_id, post_id)
     REFERENCES post(author_id, post_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
, CONSTRAINT no_self_like CHECK (person_id <> author_id)
);
```

This *requires* an otherwise redundant `UNIQUE` constraint in `post`:

```
ALTER TABLE post ADD CONSTRAINT post_for_fk_uni UNIQUE (author_id, post_id);
```

I put `author_id` first to [supply a useful index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684) while being at it.

Related:

- [Enforcing constraints "two tables away"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58970/enforcing-constraints-two-tables-away/58972#58972)

#### Cheaper with a `CHECK` constraint

Building on the *"Basic implementation"* above.

`CHECK` constraints are meant to be immutable. Referencing another table is never immutable, we are abusing the concept a bit here. Declare the constraint **`NOT VALID`** to properly reflect that. See:

- [Disable all constraints and table checks while restoring a dump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/disable-all-constraints-and-table-checks-while-restoring-a-dump/75635#75635)

A `CHECK` constraint seems reasonable in this particular case, as the author of a post seems like an attribute that never changes. Disallow updates to that field to be sure.

We *fake* an `IMMUTABLE` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_author_id_of_post(_post_id int)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT p.author_id FROM public.post p WHERE p.post_id = $1';
```

Replace 'public' with the actual schema of your tables.
Use this function in a `CHECK` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE likes ADD CONSTRAINT no_self_like_chk
CHECK (f_author_id_of_post(post_id) <> person_id) NOT VALID;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are having difficulties figuring this out because of how you state your business rules.

People and Posts are "objects".
Like is a verb.

You have really just 2 actions:

1. A person can create one or more posts
2. Many persons can like many posts. (a compilation of your last 2 statements)

[image: people like posts diagram]

The "likes" table will have person_id and post_id as a primary key.