# Create a foreign-key-like constraints that checks something more generic than equality

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

There are some situations where I would like to set up some constraints in a table that depend on values in another table.

For example, I can define two tables as:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    foo_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    max_bar integer
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
    foo_id integer REFERENCES foo(foo_id),
    bar_id integer CHECK (bar_id >= 0),
    PRIMARY KEY (foo_id, bar_id)
);
```

I would like to go a little further to ensure that all `bar.bar_id` values are lower that the “corresponding” `foo.max_bar`.

Is there a way I can set up such a constraint?

To go a little further, I’ve found that an EXCLUDE constraint using a GiST index is a great way to set up UNIQUE-like (but more generic) constraints. For example I can define the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    foo_id integer NOT NULL,
    foo_validity tstzrange NOT NULL,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (foo_id WITH =, foo_validity WITH &&)
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
    foo_id integer NOT NULL,
    bar_validity tstzrange NOT NULL,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (foo_id WITH =, bar_validity WITH &&)
);
```

Then I would like each row in `bar` to reference a row in `foo` with `foo.foo_id = bar.foo_id AND foo.foo_validity @> bar.bar_validity`. It looks to me like it should be feasible with gist indices, but I can’t find a syntax to declare such a constraint…

Comment: You cannot reference `foo.max_bar` in table `bar`. This would require an `ASSERTION` which is a generalization of `CHECK` constraint, but not yet implemented. The only thing that could work now is if you add `max_bar` in bar as well and modify the FK to include both columns.

Comment: Thanks @ypercubeᵀᴹ for pointing ```CREATE ASSERTION```; I did not know about that. Looks powerful but complex to implement (especially where performance is needed). Your proposal to add ```max_bar``` in ```bar``` is an interesting idea, but it looks quite hackish to me, and would make it more complex to change its value in the ```foo``` table…

Comment: Thanks @SahapAsci, I’ve not user triggers much, but that looks like a reasonable way to implement such a foreign-key-like constraint. But unless I’m mistaken it requires a trigger in both tables and might not be straightforward to implement for the reference table (especially for my second example).

Comment: Yes, it would require INSERT/UPDATE triggers in the referencing table (bar) and UPDATE/DELETE triggers in the referenced table (foo).

Comment: You could use a (`NOT VALID`) `CHECK` constraint in both tables, each making use of a fake immutable function like outlined in the last chapter of this related answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124019/3684. It's not safe against concurrent writes, though. (Don't have time to flesh it out ATM.)

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter for the idea. However, I don’t really understand how I should write a CHECK constraint for the referred table (```foo```) to prevent removal (or modification) of a tuple that is referred by the other table (```bar```)… Any hint?