# Name of not null constraint is missing in error message

Tags: postgresql, constraint, postgresql-9.6

The relation was created in Postgres 9.6 with use of the following commands:

```
 CREATE TABLE import_event (
   import_event_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
   filename VARCHAR (200) CONSTRAINT NN_import_event__filename NOT NULL
 );

 ALTER TABLE ONLY import_event ADD CONSTRAINT PK_import_cak_key PRIMARY KEY (import_event_id);
```

Notice that not null constraint is named.
Then the following command was executed

```
 insert into import_event (import_event_id) values (1);
```

Of course, the constraint violation error was raised. The content of the message is as follows

```
 ERROR:  null value in column "filename" violates not-null constraint
 DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null).**strong text**
```

The problem is that the name of not null constraint is missing in that message. However, the correct error message:

```
 ERROR:  new row for relation "import_event" violates check constraint "nn_import_event__filename"
```

is produced when not null constraint is declared as follows

```
 ALTER TABLE ONLY import_event ADD CONSTRAINT NN_import_event__filename CHECK(filename IS NOT NULL);
```

Is that a bug in Postgres 9.6 or is there a problem with constraint declaration?

Comment: PostgreSQL version 10 reacts the same way (not showing your first constraint name) : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=27765c3e85f02e36febf4270be21afae

Comment: So does PostgreSQL version 13.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far as I can tell the bit that goes `CONSTRAINT NN_import_event__filename` is just ignored.

the name `nn_import_event__filename` is not present when I dump the database, only the not-null attribute remains.

This does not match the the example given in [the documentaion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html)  which claims that it is possible to name a `not null` constraint.

> Define two NOT NULL column constraints on the table distributors, one of which is explicitly given a name:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE distributors (
>    did     integer CONSTRAINT no_null NOT NULL,
>    name    varchar(40) NOT NULL
> );
> ```

So, **you've found a bug**.  if you [report it](https://www.postgresql.org/account/login/?next=/account/submitbug/) it will probably be corrected fairly quickly, but the fix may be merely an update to the documentation.

Comment: Let me add that technically, the second approach of the OP is _not_ a `NOT NULL` constraint but a `CHECK`.  The former is not stored in `pg_constraint` (like checks and so on) but as a flag in `pg_attribute`, without the name.  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html for more.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're adding a check constraint when you run,

```
ALTER TABLE foo
  ADD CONSTRAINT myconstraint CHECK(bar IS NOT NULL);
```

Which produces this message.

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "foo" violates check constraint "myconstraint"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null).
```

That's not the same as,

```
ALTER TABLE foo
  ALTER COLUMN bar
  SET NOT NULL;
```

One of them is a CHECK predicate the other is a `NOT NULL` bit in a [*NULL Bitmap*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-page-layout.html#HEAPTUPLEHEADERDATA-TABLE). Presumably, the planner could use the `NOT NULL` bit in certain circumstances to plan this more efficiently, though afaik it doesn't yet currently do so.

## What's happening

From irc.freenode.net/#postgresql,

> 11:54 < RhodiumToad> `NOT NULL` is syntactically a constraint, but it doesn't currently get a `pg_constraint` entry

I believe that what's supposed to be supported is

```
ADD CONSTRAINT foo NOT NULL
```

And, then

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
  ALTER CONSTRAINT foo
  DROP NOT NULL;
```

But it seems, and I am guessing, that PostgreSQL implements `NOT NULL` not as an actual constraint but as a function of the storage system and so there is no entry in `pg_constraint`

## See also

- [Postgres: How is SET NOT NULL “more efficient” than CHECK constraint](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158499/2639)
- [Add NOT NULL constraint to large table without table scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66840/add-not-null-constraint-to-large-table-without-table-scan)

Comment: Does `filename VARCHAR (200) CONSTRAINT NN_import_event__filename NOT NULL` add a `CHECK` constraint?

Comment: @Lennart no it does not.